# Modern takes on film noir sound design? 

Tags: film-sound-design

Hi all,

Just wanting some fresh ideas when discussing film noir sound design. Have studied all the great noir works and was hoping there were some more modern examples to look at/listen to. The film we're doing deals with obsession and delusion while the score will be a classic noir-ish sound, I'm hoping to use modern techniques for the sound design.

Any guidance would be appreciated. 
Ryan.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe check out the Cohen Brothers noir-ish The Man Who Wasn't There?

Answer (score 0):

Rian Johnson's (Looper) first film 'Brick' is a great take on a modern film noir.

Answer (score 0):

Minority Report! Tom Cruise - music by John Williams - sound design by THE Gary Rydstrom

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0181689/

Great modern noir film. Watch all the special features too if possible.